# HTML Textarea under Table

Tags: html, mysql, textarea

I am preparing one form which all of it's data will be feed by user and will be inserted in mysql.

In this form I have to use long text for which I use text area, but I am not able to get tutorial how to use textarea under html table and on clicking submit button same should have been saved to mysql table.

Can anybody guide me for the same?

Comment: please add some code

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow!! Please give us the HTML, CSS etc.

Answer (score -1):

This is Html File **MySignUp.html**

```
      <html>
        <head>
                    <title>My Sign Up Page</title>
        </head>


       <body>
        <form action="login" method=post">  //from here control goes to web.xml
           <table>
             <tr>   <td>Enter your Name: </td>
                    <td><input type="textbox" name="name" ></input></td>
             </tr>

             <tr>   <td>Enter your phone Number: </td>
                    <td><input type="textbox" name="phone" ></input></td>
             </tr>
              <tr >

                     <td colspan="2"><textarea name="desc" ></textrea></td>


              </tr>

             <tr>    <td><input type="submit" value="Sign Up"/></td> 
                     <td><input type="reset" value="Reset"/></td>
             </tr>  
           </table>
        </form>
       </body>
</html>
```

This is a basic sign up from  when user click on Sign Up button then the control goes to web.xml

**web.xml file**  is a mapping file which map html request  to servlets.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>

<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
    version="2.4">

    <display-name>Sign Up Application</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>SignServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.controller.Sign</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>SignServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/sign</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

This is Sign Up Servlet  **SignServlet.java**

```
    package com.controller;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

    public class SignServlet extends HttpServlet{

        public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws IOException{

            String name= request.getParameter("name");
            String phone=request.getparameter("phone");
            String desc=request.getparameter("desc");

            if(name != "" && phone != "" && desc != ""){                
                 SignDao signDao=new SignDao();
                 if(signDao.add(name , phone , desc){

                      //redirect to success page 
                     }
                  else{
                        //redirect to failure page 
                      }
            }else{
                   //redirect to failure page 
                  }
    }
```

This is database file **SignDao.java**

```
package com.dao;  
import java.sql.*;  

public class SignDao {  

public boolean add(String name , String phone , String desc){  

try{  
Connection con=ConnectionProvider.getConnection();  

PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("insert into  users values( name=? , phone=? , desc=?)");  

ps.setString(1,name);  
ps.setString(2, phone);  
              ps.setString(3, desc);  

if(ps.executeUpdate()>0)  

    return true;  
else   
    return false;
}catch(Exception e){}  

return false;

}  
}
```

This is Connection Provider   **ConnectionProvider.java**

```
 package com.util; 
    import java.sql.*;  
    import static com.constants.Provider.*;  

    public class ConnectionProvider {  
    private static Connection con=null;  
    static{  
    try{  
    Class.forName(DRIVER);  
    con=DriverManager.getConnection(CONNECTION_URL,USERNAME,PASSWORD);  
    }catch(Exception e){}  
    }  

    public static Connection getConnection(){  
        return con;  
    }  

    }
```

This is database constants **Provider.java**

```
package com.constants;  

public interface Provider {  
String DRIVER="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";  
String CONNECTION_URL="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3030/myDB";  
String USERNAME="system";  
String PASSWORD="oracle";  

}
```